# Poetrytex package

Tags: errors, miktex

I'm trying to create a poetry anthology using the [`poetrytex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/poetrytex) package. I'm following the instructions in the [`poetrytex` manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/poetrytex/poetrytex.pdf) on CTAN and so far my code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
\AtEndOfPackage{\RequirePackage{hyperref}}
\usepackage[numberpoems,clearpageafterpoem]{poetrytex}

\newcommand*{\pttitle}{Title}
\newcommand*{\ptsubtitle}{Subtitle}
\newcommand*{\ptauthor}{Author}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I always get the `File 'poetrytex.sty' not found` message.

Am I missing a piece of code somewhere?

Comment: Check whether the `poetrytex` package comes by default with your TeX distribution. If not, it's available on CTAN; you should be able to download and install it in a few clicks using your package manager (e.g. TeX Live Uility).

Comment: You are including lines from `poetrytex.sty` itself, which are not needed: `\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}\AtEndOfPackage{\RequirePackage{hyperref}}`.  You should remove them from your preamble.  (This is not the source of your problem, however.)

Comment: @Jubobs  Miktex has `poetrytex` installed, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know (I don't use MiKTeX myself). What if you manually download `poetrytex.dtx` from CTAN, change its extension to `sty`, and place it in the same folder as your input file? Does your file compile as expected then? If so, your MiKTeX installation may have been corrupted.

Comment: @Jubobs I've removed the code as suggested by jon and downloaded `poetrytex` manually, then changed the lines with `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand` ... but it doesn't want to compile the pdf. The error is `C:/.../anthology.pdf does not look like a valid pdf document. Either the file is corrupt or it is in the process of creation. Retrying every two seconds.`

Comment: Put something between \begin{document} and \end{document}.

Comment: Doh! All I needed was a `\maketitle` in the document body. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Really?  It can't find the `.sty` file unless you use `\maketitle`..?  I can't see how that is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, MiKTeX only installs the doc for poetry-tex, and the source. So you should go to MiKTeX 2.9\source, and extract poetry-tex.tar from poetry-tex.tar.bz2. Then extract the files from poetry-tex.tar; you'll get two files in latex\poetrytex: makefile and poetry-tex.dtx. Run pdflatex on poetry-tex.dtx. You'll obtain a number of auxiliary files and 2 .sty files. Install these .sty files in \MiKTeX 2.9\text\latex\poetry-tex and delete all the rest. Finally, update the FNDB via MiKTeX Options.

**Edit:** the bug has been fixed with the 2014/01/14, cf. bug tracker entry [poetrytex: package file missing](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2299/).

Comment: Ah, indeed (+1): [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/poetrytex) only has the manual and the `.dtx` (well, and a Makefile and README).  But that doesn't explain why MiKTeX was able to find the `.sty` after adding a `\maketitle` in his document. Or so I would think despite being wholly unfamiliar with MiKTeX.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10744/sam-whited, I experienced the same problem and unsolved.

Comment: UPDATE: SOLVED! by installing manually, `latex poetrytex.dtx`

Comment: Also worth noting: `poetrytex.sty` is the only file you actually need. The other sty file is just used by the docs.